# Any examples of layout where analog ground and digital ground are connected together

Tags: voltage, pcb, current, pcb-design, layout

I have read about layout where analog circuit ground is separated from digital ground. Though, I have not seen any examples and unable to find on google, can someone help me with some pictures on how the analog ground and digital ground are separated and where are they tied together at a particular place so that there is a common ground for the board?

Just wanted to see the pictures of layout and how it looks? Can someone show me?

Comment: You don't actually do that most of the time. You use one big ground plane put position the analog and digital components on different sides with mixed signal with their analog and digital pins facing the right side. That way, digital return currents don't flow under the analog components and vise versa.

Comment: Only in rare cases where you can't tolerate the way the return currents "smear" on the ground plane (imagine water flowing on a concrete surface, it travels down a linear path but spreads out along that path a bit) do you actually have a division in the plane with a little bridge between them. And you never ever route anything over the divide in the plane. It must all run over the little bridge in the plane

Comment: Are you looking for examples with separate AGND and DGND or are you looking for examples where that separatation is actually beneficial ? If only about the first, many old manuals for DACs / ADCs recommend this separation (so read some datasheets from ADI, MAXIM or TI). But I am not convinced it actually makes sense. Here is a recent answer I wrote on the topic that covers some of your questions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/598764/237061 though it is more about a supposed separation between AGND+DGND on one side and high power ground on the "other" side

Answer (score 6):

There is some controversy about whether AGND-DGND should be kept completely separate, and tie together at only one physical location; or whether to connect all grounds into a single unbroken groundplane. Usually a designer just pursues the pcb layout until that one design works, and then they move on to the next project, so there's a certain amount of personal bias that develops over time. Either of those approaches can work as long as care is given to how the ground returns will flow. Some designers recommend using unbroken groundplane, with a strategically placed slot to help prevent unwanted mixing of certain ground return loops, but that has the drawback of creating a slot antenna, which may be bad for EMC. What seems to be the most important is getting the component placement right in the first place, so that high-current ground returns have minimal loop area, and there is minimal opportunity for self-interference.

As an applications engineer at Maxim Integrated (now Analog Devices), this type of pcb layout question comes up a lot, and a lot has been written on the subject... let me point you at some application notes and other resources at hand:

Ground and Layout for Board Designers
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/partners-and-technology/design-technology/ground-layout-board-designers.html

TUTORIALS 5450
SUCCESSFUL PCB GROUNDING WITH MIXED-SIGNAL CHIPS - FOLLOW THE PATH OF LEAST IMPEDANCE
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/5/5450.html

APPLICATION NOTE 4345
WELL GROUNDED, DIGITAL IS ANALOG
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/4/4345.html

TUTORIALS 2045
UNDERSTANDING COMMON-MODE SIGNALS
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/2045.html

A Short Course in PCB Layout for High-Speed ADCs
https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/a-short-course-in-pcb-layout-for-high-speed-adcs.html

Considerations on High-Speed Converter PCB Design, Part 1: Power and Ground Planes.
https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-63.html

Guidelines for Placing the Inductor on a Switch Mode Power Supply Printed Circuit Board
https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-164.html

When Grounds Are Separated
https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-159.html

Comment: Really nice, quick summary with supporting docs. Thanks! +1 of course.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of separating analog and digital ground unless specific requirements. You need to understand why you're doing it and it involves understanding current return paths.

I've recently designed a board where I have to introduce ground plane separation due to current return path to limit disturbance betweens IC. A mechanical ground and digital ground separation have also been done.
As you could see on the pictures, I still have a kind of unique ground plane but with the slots I'm kind of managing where return path should not go.

Here is a ground plane layer with the T slot to make a separation between left and right side and from the mechanical ground on top. The goal is to limit disturbance between left and right ICs but without doing two separate boards so I've got some things in common.
[image: GND plane]

Here is a power plane layer, the voltage is from one regulator for both side so the slot is still present and you need to do your layout accordingly. Nothing is going through the slot, you need to make your path around.
[image: Power plane]

Answer (score 0):

By definition ground = 0V where ever you define it.  When you have multiple grounds e.g. PE, Analog G, Power G, etc,  it is important to understand all shared currents in each path that may create a voltage difference at some f.

The parasitic current for crosstalk from coupling either C, L or R ( capacitive, inductive or shared currents * resistive path.)

A ground plane has an impedance coupling of \$\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$  and stray EMI from inductors to conductors must be designed to minimum the current between all "isolated" grounds, so they remain at the same potential.

This may be a complex subject and stripline theory and E/H-Field simulations may be necessary to optimize the results.

Usually these grounds are connected from the source, so they do not share conductive crosstalk, but the reactive coupling is thru proximity effects.  These may be minimized by orthogonal orientations and minimizing surface areas or shunting stray fields with a guard signal or a Faraday shield.

Considering coax twisted pair cables or STP when low level sensors must be shielded , it is important to prevent shield ground current flowing from differences in the ground potential (f) at each end. Thus, it is usually, best to ONLY connect the shield at the sensor end.  For ethernet, on CAT 5/6 STP cables the shield is not connected to DC gnd but rather a 75 ohm 1nF to chassis ground. This avoids shield currents in the range of grid and  SMTP noise but lowers the controlled impedance from the shield for the BW of the Ethernet signals.

**Noise depends on the electrode coupling and loop currents so EMI issues may be unique to demand a custom layout to avoid ground-shift noise crosstalk.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a board with 4 grounds. One is common digital, another is analog, one is for board side of ISOW7821 isolator, last one for isolated ground.

Note that there are couple digital traces crossing analog ground, but they are not even low frequency signals, they are "no frequency" ready signals triggering once when device is fully booted up.

You can also note one mistake on this board - already filtered 5V supply trace for analog sensors leaves analog ground on the right side of the board for about 4 cm.

[image]

Comment: Seeing signals crossing gaps means you didn't understand the current return path concept. There is no blame, it took me years to really understand and I'm still learning. By having all these signals crossing gaps, ground isolation is less effective and could lead to EMC/EMI problems. It doesn't seems to be a high-speed analog board, so it should be working fine, but that doesn't mean that with higher-speed it will be ok.

Comment: I don't have sufficient information on the design, I'm just looking at the PCB. You isolate ground for a certain purpose but you cross gap and provide a potential coupling way between isolated grounds. For instance the big trace a the bottom, parallel to 3V3, is starting from Analog ADC, then cross to Digital ground, then come back to Analog ADC, what's the point of having a gap if you cross it and might get noise from digital ground ? Also if you provide a point of connection between an isolated ground with the general ground, the goal is to make the trace go through this single point.

Comment: @zeqL The big trace parallel to 3V3 is 5V power to analog sensors and it does cross the gap. Which I pointed out in the text _as a mistake_. There are no traces from inside of analog ground to route over its bridge - all digital pins are outside already. It is true that there are 2x 9600 baud UART lines to isolator chip, and some signals crossing analog gap that switch once after power up.

Comment: Quickly, as comments are limited : 3V3 at bottom seems to overlap both grounds; some kind of power trace from top connector to isolator GND; same with Analog GND, same power trace as previous; top right SMT component, I see 5 trace crossing analog GND to digital GND; 2 UART as you said, but with the bottom left, there is a third trace to isolated ground. 
The thing is you try to connect the isolated ground with only a very small trace, but it is not always necessary. Look at my answer, I put slots where I need them to be.

Comment: @zeqL I appreciate your analysis. The 3.3V does not overlap AGND but it does overlap the gap, which is bad, of course. The top pins from the left are GND, 24V, 5V for isolator and ADC, then some I2C and UART channels. ISOW7821 isolator has built-in DC-DC, so my main concerns were to minimize its switching noise and have enough copper on both grounds for cooling. Yes, I saw your answer. With 2-sided PCB one simply does not have options available on multi-layer boards.

Comment: It's not easy especially with 2L PCB. But tbh, I don't think you really need analog/digital ground separation with a 2L PCB. You'll get more noise due to bad power integrity (ie what is your LDO PSRR for analog power?). For me it seems to be some kind of hobby board or small business with no real requirement on noise for ADC and ground separation is essentially show-off. All those Maxim or ADI guides are good but you need to get some step back and be critical about them.